# How to search efficiently for a file in a directory using jCIFS?

Tags: java, search, jcifs

One of my Java tools on a Unix system has to search approx. 200 directories on a Windows share for the existence of a given file by filename. Each directory has got approx. 2000 files and it takes quite some time (about 4 seconds each time) to loop through all of the files returned by `SmbFile.listFiles()`.

I've tried several approaches:

1. `SmbFile.listFiles()`, looping through each file entry with a for loop and checking the file name by `String.contains()`. In this case, looping through the array takes about 4 seconds for each directory.
2. `SmbFile.listFiles()`, looping through each file entry with a for loop and checking the file name by `String.indexOf()`. In this case, looping through the array takes about 4 seconds for each directory.
3. `SmbFile.listFile(new SmbFileFilter() {...})`, but in this case the creation of the array takes also 4 seconds.
4. Creating a list from the array and searching the list by `List.contains()`. As I have to create a new list for each directory, it still takes 4 seconds each time.
5. Creating a HashSet of the list and searching the set by `Set.contains()`. As I have to create a new set for each directory, it still takes 4 seconds each time.

All the above-mentioned approaches are too slow in total under the given circumstances.

Is there another approach which might be significantly quicker?

Comment: How are the "approx. 200 directories" determined?  Is this is a fixed list, or are you walking the tree from a single (or a few) starting pojnts?

Comment: You will get an order of magnitude better performance by remotely executing a command on the server where the fi9les are stored.

Comment: @another-dave: I'm walking the tree from a single starting point.

Comment: @StephenC: That is most likely true if  I were allowed to do that.

Comment: But the flipside is you probably won't get a significant performance improvement any other way.

Comment: @StephenC: I thought so. What a pity! I wanted to check with the community if I missed another _remote_ option. So, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @fuggi - so you've got to enumerate every directory anyway, which severely cuts down on your possibilities for optimization.  One thing that occurs to me: can you ask for names + attributes only? That will cut down on the amount of data transferred.  I don't know jCIFS, but long ago I wrote an SMB implementation.

Comment: @another-dave: I forgot to mention that I'd already tried the SmbFile.list() method which only returns the file names. Unfortunately, it takes just as long as the SmbFile.listFiles() method which returns SmbFile objects (so all the meta data, but not the file content) for each directory element.

Comment: I'm aware that it doesn't return file content.  However, you don't need all the file details - you only need the name (to check for the file you're looking for) and the so-called DOS attributes (to check whether it's a directory). In the protocol, there are various "info levels" to determine how much info you get back.  However, it looks like jcifs does not give you that level of control.